# How to filter out mail in outlook that sent to distribution list only?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

TeamA and TeamB is a distribution lists which contains lot of emails.

For example, mail sent to TeamA only - I want to put it to folder "A".

But if mail was sent to TeamA and TeamB (and maybe TeamC and couple people too) -  i do not want to put it to folder "A".

I didn't find such functionality in Outlook 2016, maybe it isn't there?

Comment: I don't know specifically whether outlook can do this, but I'd tackle it by moving anything unread for TeamA to the 'A' folder, then filter the 'A' folder for anything to TeamB... move it back to inbox, then stop the action. it would work better if there was a 'B' folder, then you wouldn't risk re-filtering items previously processed.

Comment: I'm not actually clear whether you're filtering received or sent mail, but similar could be applied in either case.

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try this approach

Comment: Are TeamA and TeamB distributions or lists of people who happen to be members of the team?  How do you know that an address is TeamA or TeamB?  It is difficult to suggest an actual solution without more detail.

Comment: Sorry I thought it would be enough. Yes, those are teams with members. How do I know? By address, I suppose. TeamA@company.com and TeamB@company.com

Answer (score 0):

When creating a rule in Outlook, you also have the option to add an exception. I'm not sure if Team A is a distribution list or a list of names so that may affect my answer.

Rule:
Apply this rule after the message arrives sent to [Team A] move it to the [A] folder except if sent to [Team B].

This should prevent the message from moving when sent to both.

Comment: This suggests a conceptual approach, but turning that into a solution (answer) is another step.  How to do that (and whether it would work for the OP's requirement), depends on knowing more detail, which is missing in the question.  That's why Tetsujin posted a similarly conceptual-level suggestion as a comment.  When there isn't enough detail in the question to provide a solution, it's useful to use comments to get clarification, then write an actual solution.  Or suggest the approach in a comment and if the OP reports that it worked, expand it into an answer.

Comment: This is good approach but what is likely to happen is situation where mail sent to TeamA, TeamB, TeamX and couple of people outside of those lists (or inside of it, people do not care when sending mails). So with your approach I would have to create rule for each possible case